# Get name of form in Twig

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get the name of form (FormType.php)

i try with

```
{{ form_row(id) }}
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form.get('full_name') }}
{{ form.get('id') }}
```

I want get this

```
 /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form';
    }
```

and use in

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('url'), 'method': 'POST', 'attr': {'id': NAME OF getName}}) }}
```

or if I can set id from formtype.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
{{ form.vars.id }}
```